# TableViewController (under a Navigation Controller) is invisible after I programatically switched to it in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a (navigation controller -> table view controller) under my tab bar controller.

After switching to it with:

```
  let rootViewController = (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController)!

  // Switch tab to interests screen.
  rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1
```

The screen takes a few seconds to update the change. Even though my tab bar controller shows that I have selected the tab.

What's wrong?